# Meissner effect

Tags: magnetic-fields, superconductivity

[Meissner effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissner_effect)

[image]

Why do field lines again get back to straight line after getting deflecting during superconducting state?

Answer (score 1):

The distortion of magnetic field lines is due to surface currents that form on the surface of the superconducting sphere. These surface currents form in order to screen out magnetic field lines at the spheres interior. The magnetic field generated by these surface currents decreases in magnitude as you move away from the currents. This is the reason why at distances far away from the surface of the sphere, you see only the applied external field (distortion due to the screening field is very weak).